# Facebook $facebook->getUser() very very slow

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've got a problem with the facebook PHP-SDK in my oauth2 app. I use login via the JS-SDK but handle most of the app via PHP.

Here is my PHP code i use to handle this:

```
<?php
    $uid            =   null; 

    include_once "lib/facebook.php";

    if (stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE'))
    {
        header('p3p: CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"');
    }

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => FB_APP_ID,
      'secret' => FB_APP_SECRET,
      'cookie' => true
    ));

    $user = $facebook->getUser(); // this take for ever

        if ($user) {    
            try {
                $uid      =   trim($user);
                $me     =   $facebook->api('/me');

            } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {   
              echo $e;
                try {
                    $uid      =   trim($user);
                    $me     =   $facebook->api('/me');

                } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {  

                }
            }
        }
?>
```

I found out that $facebook->getUser(); is slowing down my app in the last 3 hours, some times it take up to 2 minutes until the script continues. But must of the time its 30+ seconds. Is there a way to cache this or a way to speed this up again?

Comment: It's instantly loaded. I just can't find the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is resolved, the API is reacting fast enough again.

Comment: No, seems to be a problem on facebooks servers

Answer (score 3):

You can also speed up your site by avoiding

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();
```

whenever you can. I had a performance problem in the order of half a second for each and every page on my site, because I was calling that function to check if my user is still logged in or not.

This check might be essential for you, but in my case, it is not. If it is OK for your site to sacrifice that check until the user hits the logout button, replacing

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();
```

with

```
if(! isset($_SESSION["fb_<my App ID>_user_id"])) // Replace <my App ID> with yours
  $user = $_SESSION["facebook"]->getUser();
```

and by calling

```
if(isset($_SESSION["fb_<my App ID>_user_id"]))
  unset($_SESSION["fb_<my App ID>_user_id"]);
```

on your logout page. This will speed up the entire site.

In case your user is not logged in, you will effectively call getUser() very often. But this seems to work very fast, if the user is not logged in.

Comment: Are those session variables set by Facebook?

Comment: Yes, those session variables are set by the facebook php api.

Comment: This speed up my code by 20, just by adding a check on the user session -> if (! isset($_SESSION["facebookuser"])){ $user = $facebook->getUser(); ...)